# Programmatically add 3-D shapes to Bing Maps (Virtual Earth)

Tags: javascript, 3d, bing-maps

How can I programmatically add 3-D shapes to Bing Maps (Virtual Earth)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some code that should help you:

```
var map = new VEMap('map_div_id');

// Put you points together and into an array, the 10.0 below is meters above the ground
var point1 = new VELatLong(45.01188,-111.06687, 10.0);
var point2 = new VELatLong(45.01534,-104.06324, 10.0)
var point3 = new VELatLong(41.01929,-104.06, 10.0);
var point4 = new VELatLong(41.003,-111.05878, 10.0);
var points = [point1, point2, point3, point4, point1];

var shape = new VEShape(VEShapeType.Polygon, points);
map.AddShape(shape);
```

See the following for more information:
[VELatLong Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412519.aspx)
[VEShape Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412535.aspx)
[AddShape Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412535.aspx)